# How to implement a customizable free OpenID authentication?

Tags: plugins, customization, openid

OpenID is a standard commonly used nowadays. I am trying to implement OpenID on my blog, but I have many difficulties.

I tried [OpenID plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/) but it seems to be incompatible with Wordpress 3.0.

I tried also [Janrain plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/) but the free version is too limited. I would like to integrate the login screen into my blog theme style.

Do you have any suggestions how to proceed? Any other plugins? Or any PHP library that can be adapted to an easy integration with Wordpress?

Comment: You mean "it seems to be *in*compatible"

Answer (score 14):

The OpenID plugin you linked is the best one, but it has a minor bug preventing it from working with WordPress 3.0, at least when combined with PHP 5.3.

The fix can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/diso/issues/detail?id=161

Comment: If anyone cares to fork that project and release it with the bugfix, please tell us here.

Answer (score 2):

I use OpenID 3.3.2 (from the same link) and it works fine as far as I can tell. I have the latest version of WordPress and the Plugin. I have full control on the server if that makes any difference.

If you can tell specifically what the problem is, I can check how I have configured.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of notes regarding OpenID plugin:

1. I recommend [changing the plugin's version number](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13382/is-there-a-security-risk-giving-someone-temporary-access-to-my-blogs-code) so it never upgrades to the broken 3.3.3.
2. Three things I did now that helped me fix a broken plugin: Revert to 3.3.2, change my [Reading Settings](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/trouble-with-openid-while-hosting-own-site?replies=3) and making sure XRDS-simple is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say Janrain is to limited? just call the javascript `showRPX()` anywhere you want.

For instance, in my theme, I had

```
$u=get_login_url();
printf("<a href='$u'>login</a>);
```

Just use instead

```
$u=get_login_url();
printf("<a href='$u' onclick='javascript:showRPX();return false;'>login</a>);
```

It's not free as in free speech, but I think you have enough freedom with their solution