# OpenID for WordPress 3.x?

Tags: plugins, customization, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement a customizable free OpenID authentication?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-to-implement-a-customizable-free-openid-authentication)

Is there any WordPress plugin that provides OpenID authentication for comments that works in WordPress 3.0?

The [OpenID plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/) appears to be broken in WP 3.0 and no longer in active development (10 months since last update).

Comment: I saw that question earlier, but since I'm not interested in implementing OpenID myself, I didn't dig into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to implement a customizable free OpenID authentication?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-to-implement-a-customizable-free-openid-autenthication/100#100)

Answer (score 1):

Several OpenID plugins have appeared since I posted this question last August.  A collection of plugins is required to get a complete OpenID experience:

1. [OpenID Plugin version 3.3.3](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/) works with WP 3.0.4
2. It requires the [XRDS Simple plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xrds-simple/)
3. I use [OpenID Selector plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-openid-selector/) to simplify using common OpenID providers

Comment: Does anybody use any of them? Could you please mark them as "works" on wordpress.org?

Comment: The three plugins I listed above all work together.  OpenID plugin just provides the core code for managing ids.  OpenId Selector modifies the WP login page to list common OpenId providers (google, yahoo, etc).  I have been using these in my WP installation for over two years now. The only issue I've encountered is OpenID Selector doesn't seem to like some content cache plugins. Initial authorization cycle doesn't complete.