# Disable a plugin from ever upgrading?

Tags: plugins, upgrade

Is there a way to mark a plugin as "never upgrade this plugin" ?

I [can't upgrade my OpenID plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-to-implement-a-customizable-free-openid-autenthication/100#100), and this prevents me from clicking the otherwise convenient "Upgrade All Plugins" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi **@ripper234:**

Either 1.) edit the plugin header comment in the main plugin file and change the `Version:` value to something like 999, or 2.) move the plugin to the *"Must Use"* plugin directory: `/wp-content/mu-plugins`.

Here's an example from `/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.php` of the plugin header comment for Akismet:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Akismet
Plugin URI: http://akismet.com/
Description: Used by millions, Akismet is.....
Version: 2.5.2
Author: Automattic
Author URI: http://automattic.com/wordpress-plugins/
License: GPLv2
*/
```

Here's a blog post that explains the *"Must Use"* plugins *(albeit I don't understand why he chose the title he chose):*

- [**Creating a custom functions plugin for end users**](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users)

Comment: Finally got around to testing this, works like a charm.