# Login with OpenID, similar to Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: plugins, login, openid

Basically, I would like to add something like this into my WordPress site
(which obviously will also give the user an option to sign up for an account using WordPress' default sign up system):

[image: Stack Exchange login system with OpenID]

Is there any plugin or tutorial that may be helpful to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Make Your Site Social](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gigya-socialize-for-wordpress/) plugin which does most of the job for you

[image]

Comment: The plugin is not at all working on newer WordPress versions of Multi-Site installations. There were many bug reports on their official forums and not responded . Is that working on your Site?
Thanks !

Comment: I haven't tried it on multisite installation but if you say it doesn't work for you then try this one http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bc-oauth/

Answer (score 4):

There used to be an OpenID plugin for WordPress, but checking on it now shows that it hasn't been updated in a while and is likely broken for the latest version.

However, some digging turned up a post on [WebApps.StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/openid-gmail-facebook-yahoo-login-for-wordpress) covering the same issue.

It references a plugin called [Janrain Engage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/) that supports OpenID login through the following:

[image: Janrain Engage Sidebar Widget].

That screenshot above is actually a sidebar widget.  The plugin also adds the same OpenID options to your regular login screen:

[image: Janrain Engage login]

Answer (score 2):

The Stack Exchange sites use OpenID. There are [many plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/openid) that can help you implement this. One of the first questions on this site [asked about it too](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-to-implement-a-customizable-free-openid-authentication).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want users to be able to log in using 3rd party services?

If so, [simple facebook connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) and [simple twitter connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/) provide this functionality, and are extremely customizable.

If this isn't what you're looking for, please elaborate and we can suggest something else.

Comment: I want exact functionality of login like on this site. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/login

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but a quick google search yields [this](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/19/wordpress-third-party-accounts-login-plugin/), which looks promising.  It allows OpenID login, as well as a number of other services.

Comment: It doesn't have facebook integration. I think most people use that now... so I'm looking for exact stackexchange method like here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/login

Comment: It adds a) a custom table, b) unsafe, native queries. I'd avoid that plugin. Also: It leaves all stuff in DB after activating. No deactivation hooks, no uninstall. @SandroDzneladze »I think most people use that now« doesn´t really sound like a well thought argument.

Comment: @kaiser thanks for that, I didn't actually have time to read the code.

Comment: kaiser, it's not a matter of thinking, it is a fact. facebook is ubiquitous.

Comment: Yea, shure. Go, [ask that Q about multiple login options on UX again](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). Then _tell me_ that this is _a fact_.

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to do the work, however it is not free:

https://plugins.miniorange.com/wordpress-single-sign-on-sso-oauth-openid-connect

Alternatively, this is another one:

https://www.okta.com/integrations/wordpress/#overview