# Can i login with only one account to different top leveled domain wordpress web sites?

Tags: login, account

I am using Wordpress 3.3.1.

I have 3 different blog.

For example  www.a.com  www.b.com  www.c.com

Different top level domains.

My visitors want to login my blogs with same accounts.

Is there a way that users register account only one blog and then they can use same account different blog ?  Like a passport ?

In this scenario admin and visitor is me. I need to ask my questions different blogs with same account. But i dont want to register same account each blog. Please help!

If my question can not understood and then ->

Detailed Explanation

1-I have 3 wordpress blog in different top level domains.
2-I want to register myself like a visitor to first site.
3-I want to login with this account to third site

Is that possible ? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenID login on all three sites:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID
- [How to implement a customizable free OpenID authentication?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-to-implement-a-customizable-free-openid-authentication/100#100)